# No world clock on Ubuntu 20.04 top bar

Tags: gnome-shell, 20.04, gnome-clocks

I already installed gnome-clocks and added some new time zones in it.

In addition, I installed gnome-tweak-tool and enabled Ubuntu appindicators.

I still don't see an option to add world clocks to the top bar. What am I missing?

Comment: is it appearing un the dateMenu which is on the middle 0f t0p baR??

Comment: No, that's where I want it to appear. I see notifications on the left and the calendar on the right after I click the middle of the top bar

Comment: I just installed `gnome-clocks` and here is the outcome.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/wj9JP.png Did you configure anything after a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: That's strange. The Add World Clock button is missing in mine. I installed gnome-tweak-tool right away to disable animations. I will remove and re install gnome-clocks and see if that changes anything

Answer (score 7):

I had installed gnome-clocks from Ubuntu software center. Removed it and reinstalled using

```
sudo apt install gnome-clocks
```

That solved the problem.